# How do I disable Jenkins overriding tags of gradle-git build?

Tags: android, git, jenkins

I've got a little gradle-based android project.

This project gets compiled by jenkins installation for beta-testing purposes. 
Jeknins adds tag "jenkins-build-#" to git before building the app.
This is not a behavior that I'd want to have, cause my buildscript uses

```
$git describe --tags
```

for versioning the application.

How can I disable this Jenkins's behavior?

The main information I miss on jenkins builds is exact commit hash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your job's config page, under the Git section, remove the "Create a tag for every build" option that has been enabled under "Additional behaviours".

As per the [plugin documentation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin), the commit hash being built is exported as the `GIT_COMMIT` environment variable.